# Conditional form hides first class but not second select class

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a form with one question ("Do you own a car?") that when answered "Yes" reveals a second question ("How many cars do you own?"). The second question reveals itself, but the select options (1,2,3,4) remain hidden. I tried adding/removing the hidden class to the select but it wasn't working.

```js
// Reference to the hidden elements (doesn't change
// when the class list changes), as well as the select
var hidden = document.querySelectorAll('.hidden');
var select = document.querySelector('#_fid_126');

select.addEventListener('change', function() {  
// Hide all elements that were initially hidden
  for (var i in Object.keys(hidden)) {
    hidden[i].classList.add('hidden');
  }
  
// Show the element that corresponds to
// the select value
  document
    .querySelector('#' + this.value)
    .classList
    .remove('hidden');
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td class=m>Do you own a car? </td>
<td class=m><select name="_fid_126" id="_fid_126" >
  <option></option>
  <option value="_fid_127">Yes</option>
  <option>No</option>
</select></td></tr>

<tr><td id="_fid_127" class="hidden">How many cars do you own?</td>
<td id="_fid_127" class="hidden"><select name="_fid_127" id="_fid_127">
 <option></option>
 <option>1</option>
 <option>2</option>
 <option>3</option>
 <option>4</option>
 <option>5</option>
 </select></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple elements cannot have same id. Use the id instead on the tr enclosing the td

```js
// Reference to the hidden elements (doesn't change
// when the class list changes), as well as the select
var hidden = document.querySelectorAll('.hidden');
var select = document.querySelector('#_fid_126');

select.addEventListener('change', function() {  
// Hide all elements that were initially hidden
  for (var i in Object.keys(hidden)) {
    hidden[i].classList.add('hidden');
  }
  
// Show the element that corresponds to
// the select value
  document
    .querySelector('#' + this.value)
    .classList
    .remove('hidden');
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td class=m>Do you own a car? </td>
<td class=m><select name="_fid_126" id="_fid_126" >
  <option></option>
  <option value="_fid_127">Yes</option>
  <option>No</option>
</select></td></tr>

<tr id="_fid_127" class="hidden"><td>How many cars do you own?</td>
<td><select name="_fid_127" id="_fid_127">
 <option></option>
 <option>1</option>
 <option>2</option>
 <option>3</option>
 <option>4</option>
 <option>5</option>
 </select></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have multiple elements with the same `id` Instead wrap them both in an element that uses that `id`.

```js
// Reference to the hidden elements (doesn't change
// when the class list changes), as well as the select
var hidden = document.querySelectorAll('.hidden');
var select = document.querySelector('#_fid_126');

select.addEventListener('change', function() {  
// Hide all elements that were initially hidden
  for (var i in Object.keys(hidden)) {
    hidden[i].classList.add('hidden');
  }
  
// Show the element that corresponds to
// the select value
  document
    .querySelector('#' + this.value)
    .classList
    .remove('hidden');
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td class=m>Do you own a car? </td>
<td class=m><select name="_fid_126" id="_fid_126" >
  <option></option>
  <option value="_fid_127">Yes</option>
  <option>No</option>
</select></td></tr>

<tr id="_fid_127" class="hidden"><td>How many cars do you own?</td>
<td><select name="_fid_127" id="_fid_127">
 <option></option>
 <option>1</option>
 <option>2</option>
 <option>3</option>
 <option>4</option>
 <option>5</option>
 </select></td></tr>
</table>
```

Also `document.querySelector` only returns the first element that meets the query supplied. If you want to change multiple elements use `document.querySelectorAll` instead (returns an `HTMLCollection`, so you should iterate through every element)

Answer (score 0):

This is a non-unique id problem, you have 3 elements all with the same id, also you are use "querySelector" which only returns the first element that matches. If you changed it to querySelectorAll and then iterated the results it would probably work, but a different approach is not treat them as three separate elements, perhaps try putting the id="_fid_127" on the parent tr element.